# Creating Table in Ignite using sqlline

Tags: ignite, sqlline

I am new to Ignite and trying to setup ignite in my MacOs. Then want to create one table in Ignite using sqline.I am using fallowing Steps.

```
    1.Ignite Download: 
    2. Set Ignite Path.  export IGNITE_HOME=“/Users/username/apps/                  apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin”
    3. Start Ignite Node.
    4. Redirected to ignite folder.cd /Users/username/apps/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin 
    5. start ignite node.
    apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin % bin/ignite.sh
```

6. I am able to see below logs in last 3 lines

   ```
    [13:11:12] Ignite node started OK (id=c5598906)
    [13:11:12] Topology snapshot [ver=1, locNode=c5598906,servers=1, clients=0, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=12, offheap=3.2GB, heap=3.6GB]

    7.open one more new terminal.
    pwd
    /Users/username/apps/apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin

    8. Start sqlline 
    apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin % ./sqlline.sh --verbose=true -u jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/
   ```

But I am getting below Error Message

```
    zsh: no such file or directory: ./sqlline.sh
    apache-ignite-2.7.5-bin %
```

Could Someone Please guide me why I am not able to start sqlline. And how should I do that.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the version from 2.7 to 2.8 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `./bin/sqlline.sh` :)